# ES6 Object spread with string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Let's say I want to assign a new property to an object using the spread syntax

```js
const source = { payload: "abc" }
const clone = {}
clone.payload = {...source.payload}

console.log(clone);
```

expect: `clone={payload:"abc"}`

actual: `clone={payload:{'0':'a','1':'b','2':'c'}}`

FYI: If source is like this `source = { payload: { component: "correct" } }`. Then the spread syntax works properly

Question: Am I misusing the ES6 spread syntax and what is the correct way

Comment: `const clone = {...source}` or `const clone = {}; clone.payload = source.payload;`

Comment: You're spreading the string, which is itself an array of characters.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, strings are iterable and so can be a spread argument or a rest parameter – but they're not arrays of characters

Comment: Remember that `{ }` creates an object. So `{...source.payload}` creates an object. I assume you don't want to assign an object to `clone.payload`. Maybe worth noting that `{...source}` is the same as `Object.assign({}, source)`. Maybe that helps understanding what's going on.

Comment: @user633183 Sure, or they wouldn't have created a separate type. Just giving a brief explanation for a user whose username is "JSNoob" :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone.payload = {...source.payload}` means that you create a new object, and spread the contents of `source.payload` into it, and then assign that new object to `clone.payload`.

To achieve your expected outcome, you could do this:

```
const source = { payload: "abc" }
const clone = {...source}
```

That will create a new object, spread `source` into it, and assign it to `clone`.

Comment: what if source has properties that I don't want to copy over to clone, say `source = {unwanted: {}, payload:"wanted"}`, I just want to copy the payload property

Comment: @JSNoob Then use `clone = {payload: source.payload}`

Comment: Like @Bergi says you need to be explicit about what you want to pick and what you want to omit from an object like that. It might be that spreading isn't the tool for the job in that case.